# Change state of traffic light java toggle button

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe

I'm trying to change a traffic light from red to yellow to green and repeat in java and let this process be initiated by pressing one button. This is my code:

```
public class TrafficLight extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
  JButton b1, b2, b3;

  Signal green = new Signal(Color.green);
  Signal yellow = new Signal(Color.yellow);
  Signal red = new Signal(Color.red);

public TrafficLight(){
    super("Traffic Light");
    getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    b1 = new JButton("Change State");
    b1.addActionListener(this);


    green.turnOn(false);
    yellow.turnOn(false);
    red.turnOn(true);

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
    p1.add(red);
    p1.add(yellow);
    p1.add(green);
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    p2.add(b1);


    getContentPane().add(p1);
    getContentPane().add(p2);
    pack();
    }
```

I know there has to be other if/else statements but I'm not sure if this is the best direction I should go in.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){        
    if (e.getSource() == b1){
        green.turnOn(false);            
        yellow.turnOn(false);
        red.turnOn(true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Java8, you can loop any collection like this:

```
List<Color> colors = Arrays.asList(GREEN, YELLOW, RED);
Iterator<Color> loop = Stream.generate(() -> colors).flatMap(List::stream).iterator();
```

After you've done it (and saved this iterator somewhere since that's your application state):

```
actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  Color clr = loop.next();
  if (clr == GREEN) {
    green.turnOn(true);
    yellow.turnOn(false);
    red.turnOn(false);
  }
  //<continue there for other colors>
}
```

I would personally also suggest further abstraction, so that your colors are each represent an application state, so your Color is a class with

```
interface Color {
  void activate();
}
```

Your event listener will then only call

```
loop.next().activate();
```

and all necessary work will be done inside that method, not inside the listener.

Proceeding with absraction path will also allow you to add, for example, blinking before previous light turns off.

Comment: Perfect I didn't know you were able to loop colors, I should be able to get it to work now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I was you, I would do something like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvernt e) {
    // Turn off everything so you don't repeat yourself
    green.turnOn(false);
    yellow.turnOn(false);
    red.turnOn(false);

    // This is the work around with if/else statements.
    // Can be done with a switch statement too. 
    // No sure what you mean by 'b1', I will assume b1 is red, b2 is green, and b3 is yellow.
    if(e.getSource() == b1) {  
        red.turnOn(true);
    } else if (e.getSource() == b2) {
        green.turnOn(true);
    } else if (e.getSource() == b3) {
        yellow.turnOn(true);
    }
}
```

If you have any question feel free to ask.

Comment: This is what I had originally, but what I'm trying to do is toggle the light colour by just pressing b1. b1 stands for button.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it, create a `Signals` class which will manage the next light to turn on (and turn the last lit one off) :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Signals {

    private List<Signal> signalsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private int selectedIndex = 0;

    public Signals(final int selectedIndex, final Signal... signals) {

        for (Signal signal : signals) {

            signalsList.add(signal);

        }

        this.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;

        signalsList.get(selectedIndex).turnOn(true);
    }

    public void switchLights() {

        signalsList.get(selectedIndex).turnOn(false);

        selectedIndex = (selectedIndex + 1) > (signalsList.size() - 1) ? 0 : selectedIndex + 1;

        signalsList.get(selectedIndex).turnOn(true);

    }

}
```

In your code, create an instance of that class

```
Signals signals = new Signals(2,green,yellow,red);
```

And use it that way :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){        
    if (e.getSource() == b1){

        signals.switchLights();

    }
}
```

Comment: When I try and implement this code, the light changes from red to green, but stops there when I keep pressing the toggle button

Answer (score 0):

Try an AWT timer. This will allow you to set a constant rate of change between each. Just do an if (or a switch if you use an enum) for each state of the traffic light.

```
LightTimer = new Timer(1000, null);
LightTimer.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  {

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if(b1.getState() == true) {
      if (light.getState() == red)
        light.setState(yellow);
      else if(light.getState() == yellow)
        light.setState(green);
      else light.setState(red);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: If someone could please format the code, I can't format on my phone